# What is the purpose of these two capacitors?

Tags: noise, power-filtering

I came across the schematic shown below. What is the purpose of C22 to C25?

Unless they are used for differential noise, since FL1 eliminates the common mode noise present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly Y-capacitors. Do you have a photo of the board in question? What value do the capacitors have?

Comment: @jsotola it was in a magazine I saw yesterday and forgot the name. My apologies

Comment: @winny please see edit 2

Comment: EMI components critically depend upon the layout and wiring of the unit in question -- the schematic is really neither here nor there, without those details.

Comment: At mains input, they would have been too large to be legal, but at 24 V, this could be for EMI-suppression in Y-style.

Comment: The grounding topology seems to be quite weird - the 24V DC input uses the same ground that the capacitors connect to. This effectively undoes all the common-mode filtering provided by FL1. I had just written up an answer about AC-coupled chassis grounding, but then realized that it's wrong because of this "bypass" effect. Do the caps really connect between pins 3 and 4 of FL1?

Comment: @TimWilliams It was an article I saw yesterday and was just wondering why those caps are placed like that. They did not have a PCB layout in the layout. However I would imagine the layout would keep those different two grounds really tight and the area as small as possible. For instance not run the 24V ground along the enitre lenght of the PCB and then terminate at the choke

Comment: I bet C22...C25 do not connect to the input's GND. FL1 is a common mode choke, but what point would the common mode noise be referenced to?

Comment: Could you cite the article? (Images need source/citation anyway.)